# Google Translator API OAuth Authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-translate

Iam developing a multi lingual application and planning to use google translator API. I was wondering if Google Translate API supports OAuth authentication or not, document is available for using key but no information is available regarding OAuth authentication.

Thanks

Comment: I would imagine that Google would serve their authentication page based on the user locale. I'd be surprised if that's not the case.